# Drawing parabola in Graphics

Tags: graphics

```
Graphics[{Line[{{0, 3}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 3}}], Line[{{2, 3}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 3}}]}]
```

However, I want the output like this:
[image: parabola]

Parabola of different width inside the two boxes. 
There are previous posts on [similar questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65112/draw-part-of-parabola-using-graphics).
I can draw the first parabola, but not the second one. In fact, I do not understand that answer fully.

Comment: The easiest way is to use `Show` and add `Plot` with your parabola.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, this is easy to do by combination of the `Plot` with `Line`s in `Epilog`:

[image]

Choosing the right function allows the change of the width of parabola, as you see.

UPD.: I guess, code is so simple that even beginner can realize how to do it..

```
Framed@Plot[{(x - 100)^2, 10 (x + 100)^2}, {x, -150, 150}, 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 500}, Axes -> False, 
  Prolog -> {Black, Thick, 
    Line@{{-130, 700}, {-130, 0}, {-70, 0}, {-70, 700}}, 
    Line@{{130, 700}, {130, 0}, {70, 0}, {70, 700}}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an elliptic shape with `Graphics`. For example

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0.5, 1.5 (*centre*)}, {0.5, 1.5(*minor and major axes*)},
                 {Pi, 2 Pi (*angular range*)}]}]
```

[image]

In your case

```
Graphics[{Line[{{0,3},{0,0},{1,0},{1,3}}],Circle[{0.5,1.5},{0.5,1.5},{Pi,2Pi}],
          Line[{{2,3},{2,0},{3,0},{3,3}}],Circle[{2.5,1.5},{0.5,1.5},{Pi,2Pi}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: While parabola is a special case of ellipse I don't think `Circle` syntax allows this. Or did I miss the point?

Comment: @Kuba, you are right and I am a disaster again. It is indeed (half) an ellipse. My high school math marks still make sense.

Comment: It can be saved but you need to get math straight, start with: `Show[
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 1000 }, {10, 1000}, {Pi, 2 Pi }]}, 
  PlotRange -> 1],
 Plot[5 (x + .1)^2, {x, -1, 1}]
 , Frame -> True
 ]` parameters for circle are out of the blue but you can try to provide approximate formula.

Comment: The only problem is, there is no specification for the parabola. Otherwise,  appearance can be deceived, at least for a certain range. For example  `ContourPlot[{x^2/1 + (y - 3)^2/9 == 1, x^2 == 2/3 y}, {x, -1.5, 
  1.5}, {y, 0, 3}]` and `ContourPlot[{x^2/1 + (y - 3)^2/9 == 1, x^2 == 2/3 y}, {x, -1.5, 
  1.5}, {y, 0, 0.5}]`

Comment: I think you can assume someone wants to plot a parabola based on a/b/c parameters.